# Intellij Idea: Fix the position of interface elements

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, appearance

Each time I open a new project, I delete and reposition the same elements as needed. For example, I always delete these tabs: `Java Enterprise`, `Spring` and `make`.
And I always drag and drop everyone else to specific places.

How can I do this once and for these settings to be applied to every new project?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, please [vote for the related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162531).